# How can I make ethernet take precedence over wifi on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: ubuntu, networking

**Goal**

Let ethernet take precedence over wireless when ethernet cable is plugged in

**Method**

After having done a fair amount of Googling and reading I've come to a point where I *believe* what I should be doing is something along the lines of

```
nmcli connection modify [id-of-ethernet-interface] ipv4.route-metric 200
nmcli connection modify [id-of-ethernet-interface] ipv6.route-metric 200
```

where 200 is a lower value than the wireless metric, to have the ethernet take precedence over the wireless.

**Results**

What perplexes me is the reports I get from `route -n` after I have executed the above commands and rebooted (for good measure), and the fact that this doesn't seem to amount to reaching my goal

```
$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         123.456.89.1    0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp1s0
0.0.0.0         123.456.89.1    0.0.0.0         UG    20200  0        0 enp0s31f6
123.456.89.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.192 U     200    0        0 enp0s31f6
123.456.89.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.192 U     600    0        0 wlp1s0
654.321.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enp0s31f6
```

The numbers add up with regards to my command execution, but for the lines that say

```
0.0.0.0         123.456.89.1    0.0.0.0         UG    20200  0        0 enp0s31f6
654.321.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enp0s31f6
```

The first line has 20 prefixed before the 200 value I set. This keeps being consistently applied based on what I run; If I change the value for the metric through `nmcli` to say 500, `route -n` will report 20500. Why does this happen? It sure doesn't look right, since I stated I wanted either 200 or 500, not 20200 and 20500.

The second line has a metric value that I have no idea where it comes from, and I can't seem to affect it at all. If anyone can shed light on this, I'm grateful.

It doesn't look like these commands end up in anything tangible, other than affecting the metrics; I cannot tell that that ethernet is taking precedence, so I assume it is not.

**Other findings**

What I have found curious, and seem to be working to *some* extent, is the use of `$ sudo ifmetric enp0s31f6 200`. This does two to three things;

- It affects the metric of the interface (`route -n` reports all lines with  the Iface`enp0s31f6` to have the value 200)
- It affects the UI in Ubuntu (In the upper right corner I will see a visual switch between ethernet and wireless icons switching, depending on the metric values I provide in the `ifmetric` command)
- It *sometimes* throws a `NETLINK: Error: File exists` error at me. Subsequent executions of the same command *may* or *may* not result in this error

**Some system info**

- EliteBook 850 G5
- Ubuntu 18.04
- Ubuntu install made through letting the installer use the entire disc, enabled encryption, enabled 3rd party downloads for drivers, etc.

**Update #1**

```
$ nmcli c show
NAME                UUID  TYPE      DEVICE    
Wired connection 2  [n/a] ethernet  enp0s31f6 
WiFi1               [n/a] wifi      wlp1s0

$ route -n
Destination     Gateway  Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         [n/a]    0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp1s0
0.0.0.0         [n/a]    0.0.0.0         UG    20200  0        0 enp0s31f6
[n/a]           0.0.0.0  255.255.255.192 U     200    0        0 enp0s31f6
[n/a]           0.0.0.0  255.255.255.192 U     600    0        0 wlp1s0
[n/a]           0.0.0.0  255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enp0s31f6
```

Comment: Ethernet should be preferred by default. Strange. Is the output of `nmcli c show` the same as `route -n`'s output?

Comment: See my updated question.

Comment: Please update your question with those result instead of dumping them in a comment.

Comment: Yeah, I realised pretty fast, the dump into the comments weren't gonna work out.
I'm making amendments to the edit. Give me 1 more minute, and you'll have the complete output. It's done.

Comment: for the specific case where ethernet and wifi share the same LAN, using a bonding device in active-backup mode should simplify things: seamless failover and only one route: [Bonding - Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/Bonding#Configuration_-_Example_2_.28.22Laptop-Mode.22.29 "Configuration - Example 2 Laptop-Mode") (config just has to be translated to network manager)

Answer (score 3):

You have stacked problems here:

- Your cable LAN and wireless LAN are a bridge to the same subnet `123.456.89.0/24`
- You will have two default gateways if you connect the same time at those networks(this can be solved with some advanced routing an `ip rules`)
- Those gateways have THE SAME ADDRESS, since you have a bridge between wifi and cabled connection.

Maybe you should rely on external scripts to auto deactivate wifi when ethernet is plugged in like this one:

- [Automatically switch between WiFi and Ethernet](https://matoski.com/article/wifi-ethernet-autoswitch/)

Create the script `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/70-wifi-wired-exclusive.sh`. Contents:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

name_tag="wifi-wired-exclusive"
syslog_tag="$name_tag"
skip_filename="/etc/NetworkManager/.$name_tag"

if [ -f "$skip_filename" ]; then
  exit 0
fi

interface="$1"
iface_mode="$2"
iface_type=$(nmcli dev | grep "$interface" | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f2)
iface_state=$(nmcli dev | grep "$interface" | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f3)

logger -i -t "$syslog_tag" "Interface: $interface = $iface_state ($iface_type) is $iface_mode"

enable_wifi() {
   logger -i -t "$syslog_tag" "Interface $interface ($iface_type) is down, enabling wifi ..."
   nmcli radio wifi on
}

disable_wifi() {
   logger -i -t "$syslog_tag" "Disabling wifi, ethernet connection detected."
   nmcli radio wifi off
}

if [ "$iface_type" = "ethernet" ] && [ "$iface_mode" = "down" ]; then
  enable_wifi
elif [ "$iface_type" = "ethernet" ] && [ "$iface_mode" = "up"  ] && [ "$iface_state" = "connected" ]; then
  disable_wifi
fi
```

To disable the script, just execute `touch /etc/NetworkManager/.wifi-wired-exclusive`

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is NetworkManager penalizing connections that it thinks are unreachable, by adding 20000 to the metric value. From the [NetworkManager.conf manual](https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/network-manager/NetworkManager.conf.5.en.html):

> default-route of devices without global connectivity get a penalty of +20000 to the route-metric

### Solution 1

You can try disabling connectivity checking by commenting out the option `uri=` or leaving it blank, in `NetworkManager.conf`.

### Solution 2

Set `net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter = 2` in `/etc/sysctl.conf` or where applicable in your distro. Beware of [possible information leakage vulnerabilities](https://seclists.org/oss-sec/2019/q4/122).

### Background

The [NetworkManager.conf manual](https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/network-manager/NetworkManager.conf.5.en.html) has a small explanation about why connectivity checking might be malfunctioning:

> Note that your distribution might set /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/*/rp_filter to **strict filtering**. That works badly with per-device connectivity checking, which uses SO_BINDDEVICE to send requests on all devices. A strict rp_filter setting will reject any response and the connectivity check on all but the best route will fail.

In my distro strict filtering is enabled:

```
$ /usr/sbin/sysctl net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter
net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter = 1
```

The value `1` means **strict filtering** and this is responsible for the connectivity check failing. The systemd folks changed this to `2` (loose filtering) with [a controversial commit](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/commit/230450d4e4f1f5fc9fa4295ed9185eea5b6ea16e) that introduced [vulnerabilities](https://seclists.org/oss-sec/2019/q4/122), thus was reverted by distros.