# Map IP to use specific Network

Tags: networking, routing

I have (sometimes) two different networks connected with my Ubuntu system. One WLAN and one over LAN. Both are local networks, but the WLAN is run/managed by a DHCP server.

I now want to connect to the DHCP server but I can't reach it because it get's routed through the LAN connection (where no PC with that IP is).

How can I ensure, that the IP of the DHCP server is routed through the WLAN, and all other connections are routed through LAN normally, given I'm connected to both networks at the same time?

`route -n` result:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.1.22    0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp3s0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enp0s25
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp0s25
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp3s0
```

**NOTE:** Here wlp3s0 is my WiFi interface and enp0s25 is the normal Ethernet connection.

I found some things with IP-Tables and/or modifying `if-up.d` files, but I'm not knowledgable enough to either use them right or make the necessary modifications. I also don't want to have these re-routing in place every time, only if I'm connected to those two networks at the same time.

**UPDATE #1:** This is offline system with no need for security in a research state. It just needs to work, not much else.

**UPDATE #2:** I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: You say that you have two different networks, but it looks like you have ***one*** network (192.168.1.0/24) that is bridged (?) across Ethernet and Wi-Fi. I’m not sure that’s expected to work.

Comment: This is a fairly technical concept your are asking about, and your post is not very precise on a few points which makes this pretty tough to answer. It sounds like you have two distinct IP addresses configured on your PC, one for the WLAN and one for the LAN: is that correct? And your question is "how do I ensure all traffic going out to the DHCP server IP address goes only through the WLAN interface and not the LAN interface?" Is that also correct? This might be doable, depending on your responses.

Comment: How would I manage to isolate those two networks? I have unfortunatly certain limitations in place, which prohibit me from changing the DHCP Server and WLAN network, as well as some PC's in the LAN network wich require specific IPs (and subnet masks) and huge knowledge limitations in this field. To be honest, I connected everything and kinda hoped.

Comment: @0xSheepdog : That is correct. If I'm connected to both networks, I can't reach the WLAN connected server anymore (ping fails), but everything on LAN. If I disconnect LAN, I can reach the WLAN stuff, but obviously nothing in the LAN network. Since I only have one system over WLAN connected, it would be easier to make an exception for this one system instead of all the others.

Comment: Hey @Kiara-Liam .Take a look at this question/answer tuple - https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/494864/34720 - It seems to be the same scenario: LAN and WLAN are bridged, same subnet and one of the interfaces have to take precedence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type this command as superuser at a terminal and you should be all right:

```bsh
ip route add <IP-address-of-your-server-on-WLAN> dev wlp3s0
```

As it is, you’ll have to type it in every time you (re-)boot your computer. I suppose this is affordable given the overall context you described.

If your WLAN’s interface may get different names over time, just use whatever name it gets in place of the `wlp3s0` string

Also, the command above works only for the specific IP address you specify. If you have more addresses to reroute you might just type one command for each address, if they’re just a few. Else more complex configuration commands would be required.

However, from what I see of your current configuration and unless the IP address you want to reroute is precisely that 192.168.1.22 default gateway, the command above still won’t be able to connect you to the Internet when you are connected to both interfaces. That too would require additional adjustments.

Comment: Thank you very much. Internet I don't need, so that's not a problem. What would I have to do, to make this permanent?

Comment: You’d need a complex configuration, because you’d have to instruct your computer on how to detect automatically the precise situation that should trigger this very specific setup. It’s not just “when you connect to both interfaces”, because there might be other occasions, possibly elsewhere, on which you have both interfaces enabled and active. Nor it is when you connect to that “192.168.1” network, because that is a very common network numbering..

Answer (score 0):

Based on your responses in comments I don't know if it is possible to achieve what you want to do.

There are a couple of issues that could cause this on the network side; if you are limited from viewing or modifying the network configurations it makes this much harder.

- One would be 'wireless isolation' which specifically prohibits WLAN clients from reaching other addresses on the network.
- The other is your routing; the routing table above shows your default route is the wireless interface `wlp3s0`.

Depending on your OS distribution and network stack, you might be able to force traffic intended for specific destinations to use the wired interface `enp0s25` if you configure a *static route*.

The specifics of configuring a static route depend on OS distribution and network stack utilities; I suggest you review the documentation for network configuration for your OS, or provide us details on your distro version.

Comment: Im on a ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I can view the network configurations, but most of them I can't change, since others depend on the specific setup. I would like to be able to speak to every connected system (LAN and WLAN) at the same time, but as it stands now, the LAN connection prohibits reaching the per WLAN connected system.